# Creating view with fields depending on logged user permissions

Tags: django, django-views

I have my view class and I want to get access to specific fileds only for users with proper permissions. I tried way mentioned below but it take no effect. I suppose solution is very simple but I'm very new at Django and don't know all dependencies yet.

```
class SimpleCreatelView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Simple
    template_name = 'mainapp/web.html'
    if User.is_superuser:
        fields = ['title','content','Comment']
    else:
        fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: this may help http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show /hide fields in django templates using if condition :

Your Html:-

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
## Show/hide fields using css
{% else %}
## Fields...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I'm using Cripsy forms to get page looks nicer, but I couldn't handle separate fileds in HTML, so I created different View classes with arguments I wanted. But thanks for anwser :)